# How to display selected values from list box in label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list box with multiple selection option , i wanted to display user the selections he has made .

How to display that users in stylish way .

Can anyone help me on this .

Thanks 
Smartdev

Answer (score 1):

Well, on postback, the listbox's Items collection can be iterated over and the Selected property checked.

Something like this:

```
        lblResult.Text = "";
        foreach (ListItem li in lbxItems.Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                lblResult.Text += li.Text + "<br/>";
            }
        }
```

As for making it "stylish".. well that's a bit subjective!